# Why this Query is returning different results for different date formats?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I have a table named book_data with batch_dt as column name of type varchar in sql server.

when I pass the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch FROM book_data
```

it gives me the following results

```
  batch_dt
-------------
 2012-10-31
-------------
 2012-11-01
-------------
 2012-11-02
-------------
 2012-11-03
-------------
      .
      .
      .
```

Now what I am doing is getting the total count of records between two dates. Fairly a simple query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_data WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12),CONVERT(datetime,batch_dt),101) BETWEEN '11/02/2012' and '10/31/2012'
```

the result is 
**112**

and just by changing the month from **02** to **2** the query gives me **218** results

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_data WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12),CONVERT(datetime,batch_dt),101) BETWEEN '11/2/2012' and '10/31/2012'
```

why this  different behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CAST(batch_dt AS DATE)` instead, and pass the date in a language neutral manner, in the format `YYYYMMDD`. This way it will be comared as a date not as a `varchar`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM book_data 
WHERE CAST(batch_dt AS DATE)
BETWEEN '20121102' and '20121130'
```

But, this is not safe, if there was any value in `barch_dt` in a wrong format, you will get a casting error. In this case you can add `ISDATE(batch_dt) = 1` to ensure that it is a valid data time. But it is better to make this column of datatype `DateTime`.

**Another thing to note:**  is that `BETWEEN` is *asymmetric* in SQL Server, meaning that `BETWEEN '11/02/2012' and '10/31/2012'` is evaluated as:

```
DATE >= '11/02/2012' 
AND
DATE <= '10/31/2012'
```

which will never be true, the reason it works for you is that the dates were be compared as strings not as a dates. But you have to keep it like `BETWEEN the small value and the biggest value`.

Answer (score 2):

You compare string with `BETWEEN`. If you do so you need to make sure that you compare in the correct order => YYYYMMDD MM:SS would be a correct order.

If you can, add columns with type `datetime` and store real date time values in your database. If you can not do that you can split up the values and build a date value yourself. This is much slower then just use a `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` but you can make sure that it works even with wrong date-strings.

You can use `PATINDEX(),LEFT(),RIGHT()` keywords to get the values you need or you use a split() function (you can find many version google it, e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15125/sql-server-split-function-optimized). If you use the split function, then split by `/` and then get year, month, day from the positions.

But best would be still to have correct datetime values stored in your db.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM book_data 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,batch_dt,101) BETWEEN '11/2/2012' and '10/31/2012'
```

This would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You get this different behavior because you don't compare the dates but the strings/varchars.

For a `Date` (or `DateTime`), `10/2/2012` is the same as `10/02/2012`.

But for `string`, these values are (of course) different. It's just as if you'd compare `'abcd'` with `'ab0cd'`